# Como chamar uma function .js no HTML

Tags: javascript, java, html, google

Boa tarde!
Eu tenho um arquivo, onde não estou conseguindo chamar uma function, criada em .js, no arquivo principal Html. Como fazer para solucionar isso?
Segue a forma como estou chamando a função.

```
</tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody id = "CorpoTabela">


    </tbody>

      </table>  
  </div>

  <script>
    
  <?!=Chamar("Tabela-js");?> //<== esse é o comando que estou usando, porém não está carregando a função.

  </Script>

  
  </body>
</html>
```

A seguir segue a macro Tabela-js.

```
<script>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",Tabela);

function Tabela(){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(GerarTabela).DadosTabela();
}

function GerarTabela(){

var CorpoTabela = document.getElementById("CorpoTabela");

GerarTabela.forEach (function(r){

var Linha1 = document.createElement('tr');
var Coluna1= document.createElement('td');
Coluna1.textContent = r[0];
var Coluna2= document.createElement('td');
Coluna2.textContent = r[1];
var Coluna3= document.createElement('td');
Coluna3.textContent = r[2];
var Coluna4= document.createElement('td');
Coluna4.textContent = r[3];
var Coluna5= document.createElement('td');
Coluna5.textContent = r[4];
var Coluna6= document.createElement('td');
Coluna6.textContent = r[5];
var Coluna7= document.createElement('td');
Coluna7.textContent = r[6];
var Coluna8= document.createElement('td');
Coluna8.textContent = r[7];
var Coluna9= document.createElement('td');
Coluna9.textContent = r[8];
var Coluna10= document.createElement('td');
Coluna10.textContent = r[9];
var Coluna11= document.createElement('td');
Coluna11.textContent = r[10];
var Coluna12= document.createElement('td');
Coluna12.textContent = r[11];
var Coluna13= document.createElement('td');
Coluna13.textContent = r[12];
 var Coluna14= document.createElement('td');
Coluna14.textContent = r[13];
var Coluna15= document.createElement('td');
Coluna15.textContent = r[14];
var Coluna16= document.createElement('td');
Coluna16.textContent = r[15];
var Coluna17= document.createElement('td');
Coluna17.textContent = r[16];
var Coluna18= document.createElement('td');
Coluna18.textContent = r[17];
var Coluna19= document.createElement('td');
Coluna19.textContent = r[18];
var Coluna20= document.createElement('td');
Coluna20.textContent = r[19];
var Coluna21= document.createElement('td');
Coluna21.textContent = r[20];
var Coluna22= document.createElement('td');
Coluna22.textContent = r[21];
var Coluna23= document.createElement('td');
Coluna23.textContent = r[22];
var Coluna24= document.createElement('td');
Coluna24.textContent = r[23];
var Coluna25= document.createElement('td');
Coluna25.textContent = r[24];
var Coluna26= document.createElement('td');
Coluna26.textContent = r[25];
var Coluna27= document.createElement('td');
Coluna27.textContent = r[26];
var Coluna28= document.createElement('td');
Coluna28.textContent = r[27];
var Coluna29= document.createElement('td');
Coluna29.textContent = r[28];
var Coluna30= document.createElement('td');
Coluna30.textContent = r[29];
var Coluna31= document.createElement('td');
Coluna31.textContent = r[30];
var Coluna32= document.createElement('td');
Coluna32.textContent = r[31];
var Coluna33= document.createElement('td');
Coluna33.textContent = r[32];
var Coluna34= document.createElement('td');
Coluna34.textContent = r[33];
var Coluna35= document.createElement('td');
Coluna35.textContent = r[34];
var Coluna36= document.createElement('td');
Coluna36.textContent = r[35];
var Coluna37= document.createElement('td');
Coluna37.textContent = r[36];
var Coluna38= document.createElement('td');
Coluna38.textContent = r[37];
var Coluna39= document.createElement('td');
Coluna39.textContent = r[38];
var Coluna40= document.createElement('td');
Coluna40.textContent = r[39];

Linha1.appendChild(Coluna1);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna2);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna3);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna4);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna5);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna6);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna7);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna8);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna9);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna10);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna11);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna12);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna13);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna14);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna15);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna16);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna17);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna18);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna20);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna21);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna22);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna23);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna24);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna25);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna26);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna27);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna28);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna29);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna30);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna31);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna32);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna33);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna34);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna35);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna36);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna37);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna38);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna39);
Linha1.appendChild(Coluna40);


CorpoTabela.appendChild(Linha1);

});

}

  </script>
```

Answer (score -3):

Você coloca a tag script com a referencia do arquivo js na última linha da tag body. Ex.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
</head>
<body>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

Basta importar o script na pagina, pensando em que momento deve ser executado,levando em consideração que ela será lida de cima para baixo

por exemplo

```
<script src="caminho/Tabela.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score -3):

Existem duas formas de você associar um código javascript a uma página html. Ou você coloca dentro da tag script:

```
<script>
function GerarTabela() {
...
}
GerarTabela()
</script>
```

Ou você cria um outro arquivo, que pode se chamar script.js. Então você chamaria esse arquivo no arquivo no html desse jeito:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

E o arquivo script.js ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
function GerarTabela() {
...
}
GerarTabela()
```

De qualquer forma, você precisa se atentar que precisa criar ou chamar o script que tem a variável "google". Quando testei no meu computador, deu erro de que a variável não foi definida. E que o método forEach só funciona para variáveis iteráveis, como, por exemplo, listas. Ou seja, para você utilizar o método forEach da variável GerarTabela, esta variável precisa ser um list ou instância de alguma classe iterável que contenha este método. E este método é utilizado justamente para se evitar passar índice da lista entre colchetes. Ficaria algo parecido com isso:

```
const lista = [
  ['banana', 'amarelo', 'branco'],
  ['maçã', 'vermelho', 'branco'],
  ['manga', 'rosa', 'amarelo']
]

function gerarTabela() {
  const corpoTabela = document.getElementById('CorpoTabela')
  lista.forEach((elemento) => {
    const linha = document.createElement('tr')
    elemento.forEach((valor) => {
      const celula = document.createElement('td')
      celula.textContent = valor
      linha.appendChild(celula)
    })
    corpoTabela.appendChild(linha)
  })
}

gerarTabela()
```

Ou algo parecido com isso:

```
function Fruta(nome, casca, polpa) {
  return { nome, casca, polpa }
}

const lista = [
  Fruta('banana', 'amarelo', 'branco'),
  Fruta('maçã', 'vermelho', 'branco'),
  Fruta('manga', 'rosa', 'amarelo')
]

function gerarTabela() {
  const corpoTabela = document.getElementById('CorpoTabela')
  lista.forEach((fruta) => {
    const linha = document.createElement('tr')
    const celulaNome = document.createElement('td')
    celulaNome.textContent = fruta.nome
    linha.appendChild(celulaNome)
    const celulaCasca = document.createElement('td')
    celulaCasca.textContent = fruta.casca
    linha.appendChild(celulaCasca)
    const celulaPolpa = document.createElement('td')
    celulaPolpa.textContent = fruta.polpa
    linha.appendChild(celulaPolpa)
    corpoTabela.appendChild(linha)
  })
}

gerarTabela()
```

Não sei se você aprecia a minha abordagem. Utilizei apenas um exemplo bobo para poder te explicar como você pode estar gerando a tabela dentro do seu script, seja inserido dentro do arquivo html, seja em um arquivo a parte. Eu particularmente preferiria criar uma arquivo só para a tabela. Vai testando e procurando entender o meu código, se você ainda não tiver conseguido resolver este problema ainda. Boa sorte! E mais: no html, você precisa abrir a tab table para que o javascript entenda qual elemento tem id = "CorpoTabela". Se não aparecer nada na tela, você pode abri a console do navegador, que fica da aba de desenvolvedor (no meu Firefox, se chama Inspecionar), para saber se está retornando algum tipo de erro.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).